Least beth number $\ge$ an aleph number
The beth numbers are defined as $\beth_0=\aleph_0=\omega$, $\beth_{n+1}=2^{\beth_n}$ where $n$ is a non-negative integer.
The aleph numbers are defined as $\aleph_0=\omega$, $\aleph_{n+1}=\text{the Hartogs number of }\aleph_n$ where $n$ is a non-negative integer. The aleph numbers are initial ordinals.
I know $2^{\aleph_n^2}$ surjects onto $\aleph_{n+1}$. Since $|\aleph_n^2|=|\aleph_n|$, I know there is a surjection from $2^{\aleph_n}$ to $\aleph_{n+1}$. This means there is an injection from $\aleph_{n+1}$ to $2^{2^{\aleph_n}}$ so $|2^{2^{\aleph_n}}|\ge|\aleph_{n+1}|$.
I know $|\beth_0|\ge|\aleph_0|$. Assuming $|\beth_{2n}|\ge|\aleph_n|$, I can get $|\beth_{2n+2}|=|2^{2^{\beth_{2n}}}|\ge|2^{2^{\aleph_n}}|\ge|\aleph_{n+1}|$.
I know it is possible in ZF, assuming ZF is consistent that $|\beth_1|\ngeq|\aleph_1|$ so the least natural number $n$ such that ZF proves $|\beth_n|\ge|\aleph_1|$ is $2$.
Question: What is the least natural number $n$ such that ZF proves $|\beth_n|\ge|\aleph_k|$ where $k$ is a non-negative integer?

$\sf{ZF}$ proves $|\beth_1|\geq |\aleph_1|$, because we can send each wellordering relation on $\mathbb{N}$ to its order type to get the desired surjection, where wellordering relations on $\mathbb{N}$ can be coded as subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ using an injection $\mathbb{N}^2\to \mathbb{N}$. This doesn't contradict the possibility of $|\aleph_1|\not\leq |\beth_1|$, because the surjection cannot be used to get an injection. Did you mean to ask about surjections (denoted $\geq$), or injections (denoted $\leq$)?

@JadeVanadium What I mean by $|A|\ge|B|$ or $|B|\le|A|$ is that $B$ injects onto $A$. If I am talking about the existence of surjections, I will use $|A|\overset{*}\ge|B|$ meaning $A$ surjects onto $B$ or $B$ is empty.

I understand, thank you for clarification. For what it's worth, $\sf{ZF}$ proves that $\beth_\alpha$ surjects onto $\aleph_\alpha$ for all ordinals $\alpha$, which is optimal. That then implies $\aleph_\alpha$ injects into $\beth_{\alpha+1}$, which is nearly optimal.

The alephs are one of the better inroads to the beths.

A partial answer: if $A$ surjects onto $B$, then in fact not just $B$ but $2^B$ injects into $2^A$.
Since $\beth_1=2^{\aleph_0}$ surjects onto $\aleph_1$, then $2^{\aleph_1}$ injects into $\beth_2$, which therefore surjects onto $\aleph_2$, so $2^{\aleph_2}$ injects into $\beth_3$, which surjects onto $\aleph_3$. The obvious induction continuing this pattern gives us that $2^{\aleph_k}$ injects into $\beth_{k+1}$ for $0<k\in\omega$.

That result is almost certainly optimal, but I looked high and low for hours and couldn't find any references for independence of $|\aleph_k|\not\leq |\beth_k|$ for $k>1$. Independence of GCH means the only possible improvement to $|2^{\aleph_k}|\leq |\beth_{k+1}|$ would simply be $|\aleph_k|\leq |\beth_k|$, so it really just comes down to that. I'd wager Solovay's methods can be generalized to prove the independence result, but I can't find any references to such a thing being done.
